# How to manage many product attributes in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, attribute-options

We have a website and fetching the products from the third party ERP. In the third party ERP there are around **2100** product attributes. So we need to create all attributes in the Magento.

So want to ask questions that,

- What could be the impact on the website if I create 2100 attributes in Magento?
- How to manage the all attributes in the admin and front-end as well.
- Any performance issue?

**Note**: Client wants many attributes to use for sorting and filtering as well.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

1. 2.4.1 and lower, the limit is 500 product attributes
2. 2.4.2 and higher, the limit is 1500 product attributes